# Calling method on background service causes Null Reference - Should I start my background service asynchronously?

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to build a media player that uses a background service to play audio. I start my background audio service when the user clicks a start button, I simultaneously try to call a method on that background service.

I am getting a null reference error when trying to call a method on the service, possibly because the service has not started.

Should I start the background service asynchronously and use a callback or is it some other reason that I am getting the null reference. If I should do this with a call back, how do I do this?

Note: When starting the background service from the OnCreate method I do not get the error and the application behaves as expected.

**AudioActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;

namespace AudioTour
{
    [Activity(Label = "AudioTour", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class AudioActivity : Activity
    {     
        private AudioServiceConnection audioServiceConnection;
        public Binder binder;
        public bool isBound;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set Screen
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            // Find Buttons
            Button startButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.startAudio);
            Button stopButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.stopAudio);             
            // Assign Delegate Methods to Buttons
            startButton.Click += StartAudio;
            stopButton.Click += StopAudio;

            //StartAudioService();
            // If I start the audio service here I do not get the error
        }
        // Start Playing Audio
        void StartAudio(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
            // Create my background audio service
            // I have a strong hunch that start the audio service here means that when I come to the next line down it has not had time to prepare
            // Should I be starting this asynchronously with a call back?
            StartAudioService();
            // Call a method on my background service using a binder to start playing audio
            audioServiceConnection.Binder.service.StartAudio(); // ERROR HERE  // System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.       

        }
        // Create the audio background service
        public void StartAudioService()
        {
            var audioServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AudioService));
            audioServiceConnection = new AudioServiceConnection(this);
            BindService(audioServiceIntent, audioServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(AudioService)));
        }
        // Stop Playing Audio
        void StopAudio(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
            audioServiceConnection.Binder.service.StopAudio();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping Audio");         
        }
        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

**AudioServiceConnection.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace AudioTour
{
    class AudioServiceConnection : Java.Lang.Object, IServiceConnection
    {
        AudioActivity activity;
        public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }
        public AudioServiceBinder Binder { get; private set; }

        public AudioServiceConnection(AudioActivity activity)
        {
            IsConnected = false;
            Binder = null;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        public void OnServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            Binder = service as AudioServiceBinder;
            IsConnected = this.Binder != null;

           if (IsConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("CONNECTED");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DISCONNECTED");
            }
        }

        public void OnServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            activity.isBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

*** AudioServiceBinder ***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace AudioTour
{
    class AudioServiceBinder : Binder
    {
        public AudioService service { get; private set; }

        public AudioServiceBinder(AudioService _service)
        {
            this.service = _service;

        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: in StartAudioService()

Comment: You should review the sample code as you do not `BindService` and then `StartService`, BindService is typically done outside the of the service, etc.. : https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ApplicationFundamentals/ServiceSamples

Comment: Please post your `AudioServiceConnection` code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @YorkShen-MSFT I've done this now

Comment: Sorry, please post your `AudioServiceBinder` code, I will try to reproduce your problem so that I could find a solution.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT no problem. done

Answer (score 0):

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**First**, I read your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638838/why-wont-a-toast-notification-appear-in-my-background-service-using-system-tim) but I cant see your  `AudioService`'s `OnBind` method, make sure return  `Binder` in this method, usage like this :

```
[Service(Exported = false, Name = "com.AudioTour.AudioService")]
public class AudioService : Service
{
    private AudioServiceBinder mBinder;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        mBinder = new AudioServiceBinder(this);
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void StartAudio()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("StartAudio in AudioService");
    }

    public void StopAudio()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("StopAudio in AudioService");
    }
}
```

**Second**, you should call `AudioService`'s `StartAudio` method after it was prepared, give a delayed then  to use `StartAudio` method will solve this problem. Usage like this :

```
void StartAudio(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
      StartAudioService();

      Handler h = new Handler();
      Action myAction = () =>
      {
          audioServiceConnection.Binder.service.StartAudio();
      };
      h.PostDelayed(myAction, 200);
}

public void StartAudioService()
{
    var audioServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AudioService));
    audioServiceConnection = new AudioServiceConnection(this);
    BindService(audioServiceIntent, audioServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);

    // when you use BindService method, it will start service automatically, there is no need to use StartService method again.
    //StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(AudioService)));       
}
```

Comment: Hi @York Shen, I'm trying to implement this now, will update